# jQuery scroll offset because of fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following jQuery-script to scroll the page down.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('a[href^=#]').on('click', function(e){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop:$(href).offset().top
    },1500);
    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The page has a fixed header with a height of 100px. Obviously I need to scroll down 100px less, so the header doesn't overlay the heading.
I googled and I need to put in "{offset: -100}" somewhere.. but where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just reduce the header height from the scrollTop amount.

```
 $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $(href).offset().top - $("header").outerHeight() + "px"
 }, 1500);
```